# Регулярное выражение, правильное условие для поиска.

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый вечер, товарищи! Пишу систему временного хранения данных, что - то вроде cache, но храниться всё это будет на жёстком диске.

Придумал как буду хранить данные и как их разбирать, но вот к сожалению столкнулся с трудностью одной.

Вот так хранится страница :

```
[index_tools_store:id;]2[index_tools_store:id;]
[index_tools_store:header;][index_tools_store:header;]
[index_tools_store:content;]<form action="?/users/registration/confirmation" method="post">
[languages;users;welcome_message;]<br /><br />
<input type="text" id="users_registration_transport_post_email" style="width:250px;" onfocus="index_transport_ajax_users_registration_bindactions(this, 'email');" name="users_registration_transport_post_email" maxlength="320" /> [languages;users;email_label;]<br />*чуток подрезал код, дабы не занимать много места*
</form>[index_tools_store:content;]
[index_tools_store:users_groups_allow;][index_tools_store:users_groups_allow;]
[index_tools_store:users_groups_deny;][index_tools_store:users_groups_deny;]
[index_tools_store:extensions_rules_flag;]0[index_tools_store:extensions_rules_flag;]
```

Я считываю её и разбираю регуляркой :

```
preg_match_all('#\[index_tools_store\:([a-z0-9_]*)\;\](.*)\[index_tools_store\:\1\;\]#', file_get_contents($fl), $es);
```

В ответ получаю массив, в котором нет поля content :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [index_tools_store:id;]2[index_tools_store:id;]
            [1] => [index_tools_store:header;][index_tools_store:header;]
            [2] => [index_tools_store:users_groups_allow;][index_tools_store:users_groups_allow;]
            [3] => [index_tools_store:users_groups_deny;][index_tools_store:users_groups_deny;]
            [4] => [index_tools_store:extensions_rules_flag;]0[index_tools_store:extensions_rules_flag;]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => id
            [1] => header
            [2] => users_groups_allow
            [3] => users_groups_deny
            [4] => extensions_rules_flag
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => id
            [1] => header
            [2] => users_groups_allow
            [3] => users_groups_deny
            [4] => extensions_rules_flag
        )

)
```

Между скобками :

```
[index_tools_store:имя_поля;]

может быть что угодно, кроме самих скобок, а может и не быть ничего

[index_tools_store:имя_поля;]
```

Помогите пожалуйста составить правильное регулярное выражение, мне нужно получить **имя_поля** и то, что **содержится между двумя скобками**.

Comment: А что мешает использовать serialize и unserialize?

Comment: На то есть ряд причин. Например - архитектура системы, в ней всё завинчено на [v1;v2;v3;] и т.д. , система понимает что перед ней : вызов, языковой пакет или пакет с настройками, объект с настройками для вставки или вызов другого объекта и т.д. Это часть архитектуры.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Регулярка не находит

```
[index_tools_store:content;]<form action="?/users/registration/confirmation" method="post">
[languages;users;welcome_message;]
...
```

потому что `[\r\n]` не попадают под условие `.` без модификатора `s` (PCRE_DOTALL).

```
preg_match_all('#\[index_tools_store\:([a-z0-9_]*)\;\](.*)\[index_tools_store\:\1\;\]#s', file_get_contents($fl), $es);
```

Comment: Еще ее можно сократить немного для удобства восприятия:  

    #(\[index_tools_store\:([a-z0-9_]*);\])(.*)\1#s